# C# session not saving while creating webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

my area of programming expertise isn't web programming however I'm currently expanding my knowledge by studying C#.net webforms and I am working on an example.
I have a button which has this code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Course course = new Course(txtId.Text, txtName.Text, txtDesc.Text);

        // This line checks to see if I already have a course manager

        cm = (courseManager)Session["CourseManager"];

        // If I do not have a course manager, it will create one for me.
        if (cm == null)
        {
            cm = new courseManager();
        }

        // This will add a course to my list of courses
        cm.addCourse(course);

        // This will make sure that my web page can see the list of courses.
        Session.Add("CourseManager", cm);

        // This will reset my text boxes
        txtId.Text = "";
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtDesc.Text = "";

        // This will print course to page
        //lblId.Text = course.getId();
        //lblName.Text = course.getName();
        //lblDesc.Text = course.getDesc();
    }
```

and then on the webform I have this:

```
<table id="courses">
        <% 
            if (cm != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cm.getCourses().Count(); i++)
                {
                    string id = cm.getCourses().ElementAtOrDefault(i).getId();
                    string name = cm.getCourses().ElementAtOrDefault(i).getName();
                    string desc = cm.getCourses().ElementAtOrDefault(i).getDesc();
        %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%=id %></td>
                        <td><%=name %></td>
                        <td><%=desc %></td>
                    </tr>    
        <%
            }
           }
        %>
 </table>
```

I am told this is all I need to get an active session going however the session doesn't seem to be saving the courseManager class to the session and it keeps creating new instances of the coursemanager class. Am I missing something that c#.net webforms need to keep items in a session?

regards,
Joey

Comment: Could you look for `sessionState` on web.config and paste what it says? Also, are you sure you're not overriding with null `Session["CourseManager"]` some place else?

Comment: How do you know it is continually creating new instances?

Comment: How are you sharing "cm" between the codebehind and web page? Also, you can check whether your session is being kept by checking the cookie value for asp.net_session. It's easiest to do this in Chrome > F12 > Resources > Cookies > localhost(?)